# JNI: converting jstrings longer than 87 characters returns random characters

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm messing around with JNI, and I need to parse a jstring to a const char*, and it works fine until I pass in a string with a length of over 87 characters. Here's the Java code:

```
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append('.');
for(int i = 86; --i >= 0;) {
    stringBuilder.append('a');
}
System.out.println(stringBuilder.length()); //I used this to check the length until I got to the point where it would start returning random characters.
myFunction(stringBuilder.toString()); //It's not actually called myFunction.
```

Here's the C++ code:

```
const char* keyPathNative = env->GetStringUTFChars(keyPath, JNI_FALSE);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(keyPath, keyPathNative);
std::cout << keyPathNative << std::endl;
```

I only included the relevant pieces. Here's the output:

```
88
Ð0~
```

If I execute the same code again, it gives a different output:

```
88
`¢¶
```

Could someone tell me why this happens and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Also, ignore how I did for(int i = 86; --i >= 0;) instead of (int i = 0; i < 87; i++). I'm addicted to doing it (sadly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(keyPath, keyPathNative);
std::cout << keyPathNative << std::endl;
```

From the [JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for `GetStringUTFChars`:

> Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding. **This array is valid until it is released by `ReleaseStringUTFChars()`.**

The memory that `keyPathNative` pointed to may have been freed after `ReleaseStringUTFChars`, so trying to reference that memory after `ReleaseStringUTFChars` will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: To be clear, to fix it  you just need to reorder those two statements.

Comment: Or assign it to a `std::string` rather than a `const char*`.